# How to make a loop to create variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's just say that I want variables who's content increase like this: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. But let's just say that I have variables that I want their names to increase like this: `aaa, aab, aac, aad, aae, aaf, aag, aah, aai, aaj`.

In other words, I want a loop that would create the following:

```
var aaa = 1;
var aab = 2;
var aac = 3;
var aad = 4;
var aae = 5;
var aaf = 6;
var aag = 7;
var aah = 8;
var aai = 9;
var aaj = 10;
```

Just saying, the idea in variable name part, is that once it reaches "aaz", it can go on to "aba", and the same when it reaches "azz", it would continue with "zaa".

Comment: So the javascript program itself will keep declaring variables in a loop? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: why do you want that? why not use an array?

Comment: I don't see how this would be helpful as it's not like you could easily reference them. Either use an _Array_ like Dyrandz said, or use an _Object_ as a dictionary

Comment: @DyrandzFamador @vsnyc @JamesWilkins @PaulS. I started using `eval()`. I could not do much with it though. I do not want to use either arrays or objects, I would like something that can create variables to the var object/array(whatever it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
var s = ""; 
for (var i = 0, s = ""; i < 26; ++i)
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 26; ++i2)
        for (var i3 = 0; i3 < 26; ++i3)
            s += "var " + String.fromCharCode(97+i) + String.fromCharCode(97+i2) + String.fromCharCode(97+i3) + " = " + (i*26*26+i2*26+i3)+";\r\n";
```

You can create all variables all at once by calling `eval(s)`.

Warning though: Some letter combos are KEYWORDS (as in `var new = 8914;` is an error), and eval() will fail if you are planning to do it this way.  Instead, you should set the values on an object like this:

```
function createVariables(obj) {
    for (var i = 0, s = ""; i < 26; ++i)
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 26; ++i2)
            for (var i3 = 0; i3 < 26; ++i3)
                obj[String.fromCharCode(97+i) + String.fromCharCode(97+i2) + String.fromCharCode(97+i3)] = i*26*26+i2*26+i3;
    return obj;
}

var vars = createVariables({});
```

You will have a total of 26*26*26, or 17576 variables.

Comment: Nice catch on the reserved words.  It would certainly hiccup on `var var = ...`

Comment: This is the closest to what I expected

Answer (score 2):

I think it may help you

```
var cars = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var count=1;
var text=new Array() ;
for (var i = 0 ; i < cars.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0 ; j < cars.length; j++){
        for (var k = 0 ; k < cars.length; k++){
            text.push([cars[i]+cars[j]+cars[k],count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++) {
    document.write(text[i][0]+'---'+text[i][1]+'<br>');
}
```